# ActionView::Template::Error undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos

I am following [Head First Rails](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfrails/) which has been written for older version of rails. I am working on its chapter 2 project but in Rails 3. Following are my files.

ads_controller.rb

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @ads = Ad.find(:all)
  end
end
```

ad.rb

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :email, :img_url, :name, :price, :seller_id
end
```

index.html.rb

```
</h1>
<ul>
<% for ad in @ads %>
  <li><a href="/ads/<%= ad.id %>"><%= ad.name %></a></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

show.html.rb

```
<body>
    <p>
        <b>Name:</b><%= @ad.name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Description:</b><%= @ad.desciption %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Price:</b><%= @ad.price %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Seller Id:</b><%= @ad.seller_id %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Email:</b><%= @ad.email %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <img src="<%= @ad.img_url %>"/>
    </p>
</body>
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20121209174120) do

  create_table "ads", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.integer  "seller_id"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "img_url"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end

end
```

Database is populated for all the fields. `http://0.0.0.0:3000/ads/` works but `http://0.0.0.0:3000/ads/<any number>` does not work and throws the following error:

NoMethodError in Ads#show

```
Showing /Users/ava/Projects/mebay/app/views/ads/show.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `desciption' for #<Ad:0x007f7ff346c100>

Extracted source (around line #6):

3:      <b>Name:</b><%= @ad.name %>
4:  </p>
5:  <p>
6:      <b>Description:</b><%= @ad.desciption %>
7:  </p>
8:  <p>
9:      <b>Price:</b><%= @ad.price %>

Rails.root: /Users/ava/Projects/mebay
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/ads/show.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_ads_show_html_erb___4217851794431988162_70093760484140'
```

On server window:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `desciption' for #<Ad:0x007f7ff346c100>):
    3:      <b>Name:</b><%= @ad.name %>
    4:  </p>
    5:  <p>
    6:      <b>Description:</b><%= @ad.desciption %>
    7:  </p>
    8:  <p>
    9:      <b>Price:</b><%= @ad.price %>
  app/views/ads/show.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_ads_show_html_erb___4217851794431988162_70093760484140'
```

If I remove description in show.html.rb then it works fine and displays name, price, seller_id and email. What am I doing wrong?

Ruby version: `ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]`
Rails version: `Rails 3.2.7`

Thanks.

Comment: It's really tough for the book authors/publishers to keep up with Rails, but it's important for people learning to use matching major version numbers in the book and Rails version. Rails is complicated enough, and the differences between versions can make a book horribly confusing.

Comment: Could I recommend the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the 'r' in 'description' in show.html.erb:

`undefined method 'desciption'`

`<b>Description:</b><%= @ad.desciption %>`

Comment: Woah cant believe I missed it even after checking it so many times. Thanks.